# The Formal Structure of Circularity

Tags: logic

What does circular inference (benign/virtuous or vicious) look like symbolically? Is there anything I can do with truth tables or some other means to better understand its structure and what relations among premises and conclusions are circular?

Comment: $\Gamma, A \vdash A$ is a perfectly correct inference... but in the usual sense of "proof" does not prove anything.

Answer (score 2):

When I encountered circularity in argumentative contexts, at least mostly it involved natural language rather then formal systems. Maybe it is more a matter of philosophy than mathematics. However, on the other side, one might consider it a case of circularity when in logic one has an object-level and a meta-level, but no clear distinction/separation of them, or even arguments on the meta-level about arguments on the object-level that are somehow meant to show or 'prove' some kind of 'validity' or 'correctness' of rules and procedures of the object-level, which are then taken to support analogous rules and procedures on the meta-level, where there had not been any investigation, but rather an unreflected acceptance of them.

For example, as far as I recall and understood correctly, in the debate of the crisis in the foundations of mathematics in the beginning of the 20th century, when in the early days of 'metamathematics' and proof theory people were looking for some kind of 'reliability' of mathematics as formal systems, there was the objection (maybe from Poincare, I don't remember) that such investigations where nonsense since one was assuming all sorts of qualities or properties already on the meta-level in the first place, and so there would be no point in investigating formal systems for that matter.

As far as I know the subject of reductive proof theory addresses these issues to some extend. As here it seems to be one goal to understand on which philosophical bases one relies on when accepting a formalized theory, and one goal to question whether then certain formal theories (logics) can be 'reduced' to other ones in a philosophically meaningful way.